# Not getting onchange event of dynamicly added dropdown in mvc3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have three dropdownlists.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DropDownList1").change(function () {
            $("#Id1").val($(this).val());
            $("#Name1").val($("#DropDownList1 option:selected").text());
            $('#Div1').load('/Account/Dropdown2/?Id1=' + $("#Id1").val());

        });
        $("#DropDownList2").change(function () {
            $("#routeId").val($(this).val());
            $("#routeName").val($("#RouteDropDownList option:selected").text());
            $('#Div2').load('/Account/Dropdown3/?Id2=' + $("#routeId").val());


        });
        $("#DropDownList3").change(function () {
            $("#Id3").val($(this).val());
            $("#Name3").val($("#DropDownList3 option:selected").text());


        });
    });
```

In this DropDownList2 and DropDownList3 are added dynamicly.The problem is the dynamicly added dropdowns are not got registered in the page .So I am not getting its selected value from the onchange event.I added these controls as partial view.
Controller.

```
public ActionResult DropDownList2 (string Id1)
        {
            List<Emp> empList = new List<Emp>();
            Emp em= new Emp ()
            {
                Id = "1",
                Name = "Doac"
            };            
            empList .Add(em);            
            ViewBag.DropDownList2= new SelectList(empList , "Id", "Name");
            return PartialView();
        }
```

Generated Html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#CreateSubscriber').removeClass('menuHolderli').addClass('selectedMenu');
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DropDownList").change(function () {
            $("#Organization_Id").val($(this).val());
            $("#Organization_Name").val($("#DropDownList option:selected").text());
            $('#routeDiv').load('/Account/RouteDropdown/?organizationId=' + $("#Organization_Id").val());

        });
        $(document).on('change', "#RouteDropDownList", function () {
            alert("hi");
            $("#routeId").val($(this).val());
            $("#routeName").val($("#RouteDropDownList option:selected").text());
            $('#locationDiv').load('/Account/LocationDropdown/?routeId=' + $("#routeId").val());

        });
        $("#LocationDropDownList").change(function () {
            $("#locationId").val($(this).val());
            $("#locationName").val($("#LocationDropDownList option:selected").text());


        });
    });
</script>
<p class="message-info">
    Passwords are required to be a minimum of 6 characters in length.
</p>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<form action="/Account/Register" method="post">    <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>

                <label for="Organization_Name">Name</label>
                <input id="Organization_Id" name="Organization.Id" type="hidden" value="" />
                <input id="Organization_Name" name="Organization.Name" type="hidden" value="" />

                <select id="DropDownList" name="DropDownList"><option value="">---Select---</option>
<option value="516c0a18c891870f107aa74a">Choice School</option>
<option value="516d277bc8918701a44c131e">New Org</option>
<option value="516d1f492e6bba07dc245cc7">Olive</option>
</select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Organization.Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </li>
        </ol>

        <div id="routeDiv"></div>
        <div id="locationDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('change', "#DropDownList2", function(){your code})
```

Repeat for your dropdown 3

Comment: That event also not get fired.In the page source ,dynamically added dropdowns are not showing.

Comment: `.on()` bind are suppose to work on dynamically added elements, do you have any error in the console log?

Comment: It is not showing any error.But in the page source the 'Div1' is showing as empty.

Comment: If you put an alert on the first line of your function, will the alert fire?

Comment: No it is not showing alert.  $(document).on('change', "#DropDownList2", function () {
            alerrt("hi");$("#routeId").val($(this).val());

Comment: OK then last thing I could think of is an error in the DOM, can you copy the generated HTML in your question?

Comment: It is supposed to come in the routeDiv and locationDiv

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt clear, but by generated I meant the HTML with your different dropdown showed. You can get it trough firebug or chrome console. But not the source code (accessed through right click or ctr+u).

Comment: Why is there only 1 dropdown in your HTML?

Comment: the others are not showing in the page source .They are dynamically loaded.

Comment: That's the part of the code i meant to see :) You can copy it with firebug/chrome console after the elements are loaded.

Comment: <div id="routeDiv"></div>
<div id="locationDiv"></div>

Comment: the dropdowns are supposed to come on these divs

Comment: @Rn: *How* do those dynamic dropdowns get added to the page? Your code doesn't show where you render them. Just setting a SelectList in your ViewBag doesn't create a drop down in the html. You have to render one.

Comment: @rossisdead how can i render it?

Comment: @Rn: You can either write all the html yourself, or use one of the HtmlHelper extensions. Without seeing your View's code, I don't know what you know. You may wanna read up on them if you haven't: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since, DropDownList2 and DropDownList3 are added dynamicly, you need to do this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#DropDownList1', (function () {
    $("#Id1").val($(this).val());
    $("#Name1").val($("#DropDownList1 option:selected").text());
    $('#Div1').load('/Account/Dropdown2/?Id1=' + $("#Id1").val());
});
```

Similarly call other dyanmically added dropdowns also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the select options dynamically, why not use AJAX within AJAX?

```
$(function() {
    $('#DropDownList').each(function () {
        var dropdown = $(this);

        dropdown.change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Account/GetDropDownOptions',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {dropdownID: dropdown.attr('id'), value: dropdown.val()},
                dataType: 'html',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var dropdown2 = $('#DropDownList2');
                    dropdown2.html(data);

                    dropdown2.change(function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'Account/GetDropDownOptions',
                            type: 'GET',
                            data: {dropdownID: dropdown2.attr('id'), value: dropdown2.val()},
                            dataType: 'html',
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                var dropdown3 = $('#DropDownList3');
                                dropdown3.html(data);

                                dropdown3.change(function() {
                                    //....same thing as above pretty much
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Then your controller action, GetDropDownOptions, would examine the DDL ID and selected value, understand what options it needed, then return the options as HTML. Or as a more elegant solution, you could have it return an object as json ( return Json(object) ) and then programatically create the elements in your javascript. You'd have to switch the dataType in the $.ajax to 'json'.

This way you have the dropdown change event after it has loaded the options. This change event loads DropDownList2's options and change event, which will load DDL3's options.

Haven't tested the code, but this idea will work. This sample assumes you already have the first DDL options loaded, but it seems you'll have to have add another layer of ajax to load those in as well. It also assumes the  and DDL3 are already on the DOM at page load. You could add them to the DOM in your html to get this example to work, or change the IDs in the javascript to some  container.